# How to Store the Data, such as books?

Tags: mysql, database, blob

In my database, I've more than 1000 books and average book around 100 pages (maybe more or less). I'm thinking:

- Is it possible to store each book in a single field? Like:

  ```
  INSERT INTO bookContent VALUE("book contents from first page to end...");
  ```

where `bookContent` will be the entire book content.

- If it is not good idea to store them into MySQL, than what is the best way?

Comment: We'd need more information about what you're trying to do to provide informed answers.

Comment: What precisely is a "MySQL cell"?

Comment: Based on the query he posted, i guess 'cell' means one row.

Comment: @Chris : he means a single field.

Comment: Are you wanting to search the book later? Do you want to return the entire book contents? Is it just for archiving?  Personally I like to break up my data into logical parts, but like Michael P said, it really depends on what you're planning to do with the stored data. Your idea of storing it as a single field can be done (if you use a field type with a high enough value), but in most use-cases, it's not going to be very efficient. The only reason I can think of is if you wanted to use the DB as a general file system for sharing and sending, etc. Look for the keyword `BLOB` on Google.

Comment: Thanks Anthony. Actually, I'm thinking to create a website for people to read books. Therefore, each time if people clicked the book name, then server side will load the books to public. I'm thinking if store those books as files, what is the benefit and what is disadvantage of it?  So as using SQL?  I thought that using SQL to store like a book contents into a field is not good idea. To store only consist of 100 characters as a file, is not good idea either. Then what is compromise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short yes, but because of a max length for most types of data you will need to use a binary data type such as blob which max is so high you will never reach it.(most likely)

You probably will have to escape your string with a function like `mysql_real_escape_string()`
to handle special characters.  I was storing lyrics and had to escape the string to prevent errors.

in perl `$connect->quote("book contents from first page to end...");`
before attempting to insert the value into a table.

I am not sure it is wise to just insert the whole book by itself.  There should be at least a unique book # field so, if you want, you can have another table with author, title, publisher, and etc.  If you don't have other fields in the table or another table you won't be able to easily query just certain books.

You want to see all the Sherlock Holmes books.... It won't be easy.  The database will run incredible slow because it has to search the content of every book for "Sherlock Holmes".

Now if your table has author, publisher, title, and etc then

```
select * from book where author="Sir Aurthur Conan Doyle";
select * from book where title="Sherlock Holmes";
```

These queries will run orders of magnitude faster than this query.

```
SELECT * FROM book WHERE book LIKE '%Sherlock Holmes%';
```

Depending on the actually size of each book in kilo or mega bytes the above query could have your cpu at 99% for a while.

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-type-overview.html
for data type sizes.